# System Tray Icons

Tags: 14.04, unity, login, screen, system-tray

My system tray icons appear to be little square boxes instead of icons in login screen. On my user desktop however, they show up as the correct icons. This appears to have started after playing with Ubuntu Tweak. Everything else is working fine. Any ideas to get those little icons looking like little icons in the login screen? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (Ctrl Alt T)

Now you need to reset the Ubuntu  tweak tool.

```
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

Then type:

```
$ unity-reset
```

If this does not work you can try to reinstall ubuntu-desktop

First login to tty(Ctl Alt F1)

After you login to the tty type

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

(you can also run this on " safe mode" `sudo apt-get aptitude install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`)

After this completes reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I did try that but it didnt work.

Comment: i have updated my answer